# переход на другую вкладку tabBar по тапу на ячейку таблицы, с передачей данных

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, controller

Задача такая, есть 3 вкладки в табБаре, главная+История+карта.
Вкладка история - это tableView, по нажатию на одну из ячеек - делается переход на вкладку КАРТА, вместе с этим происходит и передача данных.
Делал переход через show, передавал данные по сегвею, и все было хорошо, НО показанный контроллер с картой, с успешно полученными данные, НЕ является частью tabBar, он открывается отдельно, соответственно нижняя часть с баром кнопок табБара - мертвая, просто белая полоса.

Как мне по тапу на ячейку/кнопу переходить на другую вкладку TabBar, передавая данные и не покидая TabBarController?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
tabBarController.selectedIndex = 1
```